# Group together mysql results by ID

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database of page visits to my website, each visit has a unique ID but if a visitor views multiple pages during their visit, each page view shares as visit ID.

Table Structure Below,

```
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `url` text NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `timedate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `visit_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `url1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `page_time` time NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
```

Below is a link to a screenshot of my page, as you will see at the moment all of the visits are listed in single boxes, what i want to do is group the results together in blocks where they share the same visit_id.

http://www.lst-technologies.co.uk/pageviews.html

I have tried the following code:

```
 SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE client_id='$client_id' AND visit_id ='$id' GROUP BY visit_id LIMIT $start, $limit
```

but this simply groups the results but just shows one entry.

CODE FOR CURRENT DISPLAY

```
 SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE client_id='$client_id' AND visit_id ='$id' LIMIT $start, $limit
```

Comment: What are the values of your $start and $limit variables?

Comment: Thats just the pagination for the page so start is 0 and limit is the number of records to display

Comment: Remove the GROUP BY clause if you want all visits for a particular id

Comment: How are you populating that table in the screenshot? Can you add your code for that?

Comment: Thanks I have just added the code it's the same as the previous example just without the GROUP BY

Answer (score 1):

You have a basic misunderstanding of what `GROUP BY` is for. It's not for collecting related rows together, it's for combining related rows into one row in the result, when using aggregation functions such as `COUNT()`, `SUM()`, and `MAX()`.

To get related rows together in the result, use `ORDER BY`, making the column you care about the first column in the ordering list, e.g.

```
ORDER BY visit_id, timedate
```

If you want to show the visit ID only once in the output, the PHP loop that processes the result should contain something like:

```
if ($row['visit_id'] != $last_visit_id) {
  $last_visit_id = $row['visit_id'];
  echo "Visit ID: $last_visit_id\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already filtering to a certain visit_id, you don't really have to use GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply group by something and still `SELECT *`. This does not make sense in SQL, but MySQL thinks otherwise and will return one random result in every column that was NOT mentioned in either the GROUP BY or is used with a grouping function like COUNT(), MAX(), MIN(), GROUP_CONCAT(), SUM() etc.

You have to mention explicitly the columns you want to see in the result, and which kind of result if more than one source row should be mixed into one result row.